# What function to call when trying to record the length of a key press? (Processing)

Tags: java, arrays, processing, keypress

If for example I want to record that I pressed the b key and want to record the length of time that it was held down for, how would i do that?

Comment: You either need Swing or JNativeHook.

Comment: No need for all that complicated Java stuff, Processing wraps up all the interaction code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Super easy with Processing. Take a look at [keyPressed()](https://www.processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) and [keyReleased()](https://www.processing.org/reference/keyReleased_.html).

```
// create a variable to store the time
int t = 0;

void setup() {
  // whatever you need to do here
}

void draw() {
  // do other stuff here
}

// when 'b' key is pressed, store the current
// time in milliseconds since the program started
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'b') {
    t = millis();    
  }
}

// when the 'b' key is released, subtract the start
// time from the current time to get the duration
void keyReleased() {
  if (key == 'b') {
    t = millis() - t;
    println("b key held for " + t + " milliseconds");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of possible approaches:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.event.KeyEvent;

// this map holds currently pressed keys
private Map<Character, Record> map = new HashMap<Character, Record>();

public void setup() {
...
}

public void draw() {
...
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    char key = event.getKey();

    // only if map doesn't hold this key yet
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {

        // create new record with this key and start timestamp
        Record record = new Record(key, millis());
        map.put(key, record);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    char key = event.getKey();

    // retrieve record for this key
    Record record = map.get(key);

    // store release timestamp (milliseconds from program startup)
    record.releaseTime = millis();

    map.remove(key);

    // now record has full info
    println(key + ", time: " + (record.releaseTime - record.pressedTime));
}

class Record {
    char key;
    long pressedTime;
    long releaseTime;

    Record(char key, long pressedTime) {
        this.key = key;
        this.pressedTime = pressedTime;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...